# reading second word of every line using spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to read/print second word of every line.

input->>people are not as beautiful as they look,
as they walk or as they talk.
they are only as beautiful  as they love,
as they care as they share.

output->>
are
they
are
they

Comment: Hi, you'll likely get a better response if you post a specific question & what you have tried. Please check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for tips.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this :

```
    val myDF=spark.read.text("<path>")
    import org.apache.spark.sql._
    import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
    val rdd=myDF.rdd.map(_.mkString("")).map(f=> Row(f.split(" ")(1)))
    val schema:StructType  = (new StructType).add("values",StringType )
    val result=spark.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)
    result.show()
```